# How can I access to folders files outside of wwwroot with IIS?

Tags: iis, windows-server-2019

I am using windows server 2019 and I have a domain given by **azure**. The webapp works great but I am wondering if there is a possibility to configure the IIS so I can access to any folder inside the server. For example I have a text file in the server's desktop called testing.txt and I want to access to that file through the server name and Uri like:

`http://test.eastus.cloudapp.azure.com/Users/Fredy/Desktop/testing.txt`

but gives me the following error:

[image]

I am asking if there is a documentation for configuring IIS for such scenarios? I know this is dangerous but maybe if there is a possibility I can configure which folders can be seen. Files that are being accessed can be images, texts, connectionStrings, etc.

Is it possible? How do I do this?

Comment: The IIS web root folder is configurable but I never thought of making the desktop or disk root folder as web root folder. We configured the wwwroot as an external shared drive to allowed others in the organization to copy file to it.

Comment: I am not trying to make Desktop as root folder we just want to access to files and it can be any folder Desktop, documents, Pictures or folders inside program files, we just want to access to files while maintaining wwwroot as root folder for it.  I want this way so my API can access to the files. Is this possible?

Comment: I think I have solved this, I just have to create a new app and selecting folders that contains the files so my API can point to them. This is the easiest way I figured out.

Comment: I'm not sure this can be done (allow to be done) in an Azure VM, but IIS_USER (IIS account is running under) is restricted to have full permissions to WWWROOT but not the parent directory, if you're windows guy, then you know where I'm heading with this. Remove the inheritance permissions and give it full access to the parent on down. You already acknowledged the security implications of doing this and Azure may intervene.

Comment: @ReyneerLeon: Can you add this as a dedicated answer? It's honestly the easiest idea ever, and it also retains all possible safety features without exposing too many folders outside. It's a fast and workable solution.